# User input not being saved to MongoLab collection

Tags: mongodb, node.js, heroku, express, mlab

This is all ran on Heroku and what I'm trying to do is get whatever the user puts for their name and password on signup and save it to MongoLab collection 'Users'.

I have Node.js, Express, and Mongodb

I have my db open and config and what not to the mongolab host and port.

```
var db = new mongo.Db('dbname', new mongo.Server('host', port, {auto_reconnect: true}));

var mongo_config = {
    host: 
    port: 
    dbname: 
    username:
    password:
};

db.open(function(err, clien) {
    //help 1
});
```

and my code to get the express input for when they signup

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        //help 2
    console.log(req.body.password);
    console.log(req.body.name);
    res.redirect('/signin');
});
```

So help 1: What do I do there?

Help 2: Do I put a mongodb code there like collection.insert? If so how do I make the connection from web app to database?

Answer (score 3):

For "help 1" this is code that you want to execute when a database opens successfully. For example you might want to open collections with `db.collection(collectionname, callback)` and assign them to variables. You might also want to put some code in here that controls first launching the actual server, since you don't want to run the webserver unless the database connection has opened successfully. You should also check the `err` for all your mongo commands.

For "help 2" you should refer to the node driver docs here: https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/tree/master/docs

You can do find/update/insert calls via the node driver to mongodb. For the most part, these are very similar to mongo commands on the JS shell, except they take a callback argument, obviously.